# RSS Reader and then Grabbing the page content

Tags: java, rss, nlp, web-crawler

I have integrated the RSS Reader in my application. 
How do I grab the Webpage with the RSS Feed URL?
Is there any free api which does this directly in Java using the URL?

I have to process the content of the webpage (news articles to be precise) and do some algorithmic stuff with that.

The problem now is to do a small part of Crawler. Is there any free light weight api's?

Comment: What do you mean "grab the webpage with the RSS feed URL"? That the user should input `http://stackoverflow.com/` and your application parses this page to get `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds`?

Comment: Or do you already have `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/`, found there a link to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048440/rss-reader-and-then-grabbing-the-page-content` and want to load this page?

Comment: Let's say I receive continuous RSS feeds from a News site and I want to retrieve all the information from that URL. (The RSS feeds are mostly links and some description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the "content" of any URL, look at the `java.net.URL` class. It has some useful methods to get the content, like `openConnection()` and `openStream()` to get the content.